# DRCSim 2.2.0 installation on 32 bit machine

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have installed gazebo 1.5 already and wanted to see how a humanoid robot is controlled in gazebo. I think Atalas is a good example to benchmark and tried to install DRCSim. The tutorial says 32 bit machine users should compile the source to use the latest version. I tried to follow the instruction, but it said /usr/local/share/gazebo/setup.sh was not found. There was another path for the setup.sh, /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh and I re-tried with the path. However, during 'make', errors were occured at around 77%.

```
 [ 77%] [ 77%] Built target VRCPlugin
Built target gazebo_ros_api_plugin
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/biped/drcsim-2.2.0/ros/atlas_msgs/../../plugins/AtlasSimInterface_1.0.3/lib64/libAtlasSimInterface.so when searching for -lAtlasSimInterface
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/biped/drcsim-2.2.0/plugins/AtlasSimInterface_1.0.3/lib64/libAtlasSimInterface.so when searching for -lAtlasSimInterface
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lAtlasSimInterface
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [lib/libAtlasPlugin.so] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/AtlasPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 77%] [ 77%] Built target gazebo_ros_controller_manager
[ 77%] Built target gazebo_ros_camera_utils
Built target gazebo_ros_imu
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [ros/atlas_msgs-prefix/src/atlas_msgs-stamp/atlas_msgs-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ros/CMakeFiles/atlas_msgs.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2222/drcsim-2.2.0-installation-on-32-bit-machine./) by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm afraid that the AtlasInterfaceLibrary (shipped as a binary with DRCSim) is only available in 64bits at this moment, so trying to compile the source without manually making changes to take the library out of the code, is not going to work.

If you need a fully working version of DRCSim, it's **totally** recommended to use a 64bits system.

Some **experimental** work was done to remove the AtlasInterfaceLibrary from the 2.2.0 version of the code, you can find it in [drcsim 2.2.0 32bits branch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/commits/branch/drcsim_2.2.0_32bits) of drcsim. It's totally **untested** and lacks of the functionality provided but the AtlastInterfaceLibrary.

Again, for a real experience of using DRCSim at this moment, please go for a 64bits version.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wonyoung](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/279/wonyoung/) on 2013-04-03**:
Thank you for the answer. I thought I could install the 32bit version if I compiled the source. Somehow, I should get a 64 OS. Actually, I just realized my laptop supports 64 bit OS. :)